# Integration by Parts and Convergent/Divergent Series Calculus

Tags: integration

We are asked to integrate:

$$\int x (lnx) dx$$

Integration by parts gives us: (using L-I-A-T-E)

$$u = lnx$$

$$ du = (1/x)dx$$

$$ dv = xdx $$

We find v by integrating dv:

$$ v = (1/2)x^2 $$

Recall:

$$uv - \int v du$$

Performing our substiutions:

$$ (1/2)x^2lnx -(1/2)\int xdx$$

This gives results as:

$$(1/2)x^2(lnx-(1/2))$$

Now, taking the limit of the solution:

$$lim [(1/2)x^2(lnx-(1/2))] -> (1/4) as t -> infinity$$

If I take the limit of my solution as x approaches infinity my solution approaches (1/4) and therefore is a convergent series.

Comment: The second integral should be $\int \frac{x}{2}\,dx$. And don't forget the $+C$.

Comment: +C has been omitted.

Comment: As to a *definite* integral, such as $\int_1^\infty x\ln x\,dx$, the limit of $\int_1^M x\ln x\,dx$ does not exist. This is obvious without calculation, since $x\ln x$ is positive for $x\gt 1$, and does not approach $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $\int x dx$ should be $\int \frac12 x dx$.  Then your final answer will be $\frac12 x^2(\ln x-\frac12)$